# I get the BSOD mutiple times everyday. How do I fix this?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I'm having a serious issue with my computer. For the last 2 weeks, my laptop (HP EliteBook 840, i5 2.30 GHz, 8 GB RAM, Windows 10 Pro 64 bit) has been crashing and showing me the BSOD multiple times per day.

I have done all I could think of to try to fix the issue, but nothing seems to be working.
Here is a list of what I have tried:

1. Update Windows - apply patches and security updates.
2. Uninstall all unnecessary applications.
3. Update all drivers.
4. Fix registry entries.
5. Disable google chrome addons (one crashed before a BSOD appeared, so I figured it was worth a shot.)
6. Reset Windows 10 through the Windows Settings (Win + I) panel.
7. Ran sfc /scannow and chkdsk from Command Prompt (no errors).
8. Tried to get the memory dump, but no files created.
9. Tried to enter Safe Mode, but the menu does not show up (maybe I'm doing something wrong here.)
10. Run a hardware check through BIOS (Memory and Hard Disk) - no issues.
11. Checked Windows System Logs in Event Viewer which shows either "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly." or "The previous system shutdown at {time} on {date} was unexpected."

Currently I have only 7 programs showing as installed on my system - the only ones I have installed myself are Google Chrome and Atlassian's HipChat (for work). The other 5 are Intel Graphics Driver, Microsoft OneDrive, Synaptics Pointing Device Driver and Realtek's Card Reader & High Definition Audio Driver.

The BSOD has also appeared as the Orange Screen of Death multiple times, and says "Your PC ran into some problems and needs to restart. We're just collecting some error info and then we'll restart for you." However, the progress of the error collection never goes past 0% before it restarts. It also shows the stop code as "CRITICAL PROCESS DIED" (most frequent message) or "WINDOWS STORE EXCEPTION" and one other I can't recall right now. It asks me to go to windows.com/stopcode but nothing there has helped solve the problem.

Also, once it auto restarts after the BSOD/OSOD, the BIOS itself crashes(?) and doesn't proceed from there. I tried to enter the System Menu, but it just sat there highlighted and frozen. In fact while writing this in notepad an nothing else open (I type at ~120 wpm), the system has frozen and restarted 10 times.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit: After changing a registry value to include DisplayParameters (DWORD) for the BSOD I have a code that appeared - 0xFFFFB00E4C93B780 followed by 0x0000000000000000 three times.

Edit 2: Yet once more 0xFFFFD9D08B8C2480 followed by 0x0000000000000000 three times.

Comment: If you have performed a Reset then it's unlikely software (driver) causing the problem.  Without the .dmp files we can't help

Comment: share all files from **C:\windows\minidump**

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, unfortunately, this is a problem with the Windows 10 and laptop. In many laptops, the provided drivers do not suit with the Windows 10. I was also facing this issue few months back which was so frustrating. I have solved my issue by downgrading to Windows 7 which does not show BSOD anymore. You may try to downgrade your version of Windows and it will work surely as I have also tested this in some of my friends' laptop.

Even if you want to stick yourself with Windows 10 as the User Interface of Windows 10 is pretty cool, I can suggest you one solution that to stop the automatic driver installation of Windows. I don't know whether it will work for your case or not but I know it works. Windows 10 does not provide built-in option to disable automatic updates which is the main problem we face. Try to follow the instructions [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-automatic-driver-installation-in-windows-vista/) to disable automatic update in Windows 10.

Comment: I had the auto update feature of Windows 10 disabled by making my Internet connection as a metered one. I was using the laptop with Windows 10 for ~7 months with no issues when the BSOD's started popping up. I will downgrade if nothing else works. Thanks.